# no more space on home but on dev/sda4

Tags: fedora, partition

I have no more free space in my `/home` but on the whole filesystem I have enough. How do I use the free 37GB on `/home`?

I am running Fedora 20, by the way.

```
[stefan@heimo ~]$ df -h
Dateisystem               Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda4                   50G     11G   37G   22% /
devtmpfs                   7,8G       0  7,8G    0% /dev
tmpfs                      7,8G    876K  7,8G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      7,8G    948K  7,8G    1% /run
tmpfs                      7,8G       0  7,8G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                      7,8G     16K  7,8G    1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                  477M    114M  334M   26% /boot
/dev/sda5                   53G     49G  890M   99% /home
/dev/sda1                  200M    9,3M  191M    5% /boot/efi
192.168.1.5:/var/data/app  7,3T    5,2T  1,7T   76% /home/stefan/****/app
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes how can i use the 37gb free space on /home?

Comment: Re-partition your disk.  Or move `/home` to a directory on `/dev/sda4`.  Or just make a symlink to a directory on `/dev/sda4` owned by you.  Or use `lvm` to join `/` and `/home` (not a good idea).  You didn't really expect a _nice_ solution, did you. :)

Comment: how can i make a symlink to /dev/sda4 because "sda4" is a file

Comment: Who said anything about linking __to__ `/dev/sda4`.  Rather something like this: `mkdir /extension; chown blacksunshine:blacksunshine /extension; ln -s /extension ~`.  It doesn't add space to your `$HOME`, it just makes using free space in your root less of a pain in the rear.